# Get Text/Title of Tab inside Fragment Java in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-tabs

How can i get text/title of Tab inside TopFreeFragment.java?

I want to know which tab is selected and accordingly load the webview. How can i do that?

I have tried using sharedPreferences but that is not the correct way and neither it works properly.

Here i want to show Toast of the tab title inside the TopFreeFragment.java

```
public class YouTube_Toolbar extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.you_tube__toolbar);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new TopFreeFragment(), "TUESDAY");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new TopFreeFragment(), "WEDNESDAY");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new TopFreeFragment(), "THURSDAY");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new TopFreeFragment(), "FRIDAY");
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

---

```
 public class TopFreeFragment extends Fragment {

WebView webView;
Button download;

public TopFreeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_free, container, false);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would write a `newInstance()` method and a `getTitle()` method in your Fragment and pass the name in through a `Bundle`.

Something like this:

**TopFreeFragment.java**

```
public class TopFreeFragment extends Fragment {
    WebView webView;
    Button download;

    public TopFreeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static TopFreeFragment newInstance(String title) {
        TopFreeFragment fragment = new TopFreeFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putCharSequence("title", title);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_free, container, false);
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        return args.getCharSequence("title", "NO TITLE FOUND");
    }
}
```

Then add the fragments to your `viewPagerAdapter` like this:

**YouTube_Toolbar.java**

```
public class YouTube_Toolbar extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.you_tube__toolbar);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(TopFreeFragment.newInstance("TUESDAY"), "TUESDAY");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(TopFreeFragment.newInstance("WEDNESDAY"), "WEDNESDAY");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(TopFreeFragment.newInstance("THURSDAY"), "THURSDAY");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(TopFreeFragment.newInstance("FRIDAY"), "FRIDAY");
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
}
```

To get the title of the fragment from within the fragment, simply call `getTitle()`. You can pass whatever you want the title to be as the argument of the `newInstance(String title)` method.

Comment: it works partially

`public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        String title = getTitle();

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }`


Here toast gives 2 output when a tab is selected (like here "TUESDAY" & "WEDNESDAY" )

Comment: What part is not working? Try adding that code to the `onCreateView()` method instead of `onActivityCreated()`.

Comment: same is the case in `onCreateView()`

Comment: Again, what exactly is not working? Can you show me some output or your code or something? It's hard to debug without some more info. Can you show me your `viewPagerAdapter` code?

Answer (score 0):

try to pass in bundle title name and get in `onAttah()` callback method and use that in your fragment.
`ViewPagerAdapter` class code

```
Fragment fragment = new ViewOrderTabFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title","tabOne");
        fragment.setArguments(args);
```

fetch title in `Fragment(ViewOrderTabFragment)` like this

```
String tabName="";
@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    if (getArguments()!=null) {
        tabName=getArguments().getString("position", "");
    }
    super.onAttach(context);
}
```

**note:** this will help us to logs when we have dynamic tabs with same fragment